# Android - Google maps to show location name instead of longitude and latitude

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, geolocation

I have this code to start a navigation activity

```
String uri = "geo:0,0?q=<lat>,<long>";
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Google Maps starts and show the correct location on the map but at the bottom panel, instead of the location name to find a route to, I see the latitude and longitude I've sent.

The lat/long data makes it certain about the location I want but shows this info while sending it the location name might show it as I expect but it might get confused with several similar locations. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can show a name in the marker in google maps using the following URI:

```
   String uri = "geo:0,0?q=34.99,-106.61(Treasure)";
```

As explained in [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I fully understand what you're asking for, but it sounds like you want [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding). You can convert your Lat/Lng to a location with it. It generally gives a very detailed response, usually including the street address number, so that's one way to distinguish similar locations.